# Why does mutt fail when I call it from my Perl CGI script?

Tags: perl, email, mutt

I have developed  a database with the use of Perl CGI with C++. I have problem in sending the results to mail. I used the following code:

```
print LOG "[",`date`,"] Sending mail to $email\n";  
system (qq{mutt -s "MMM" -a $zip_file $email < $job_id});  
if ( $? == 0) {  
        print LOG "[",`date`,"] Sending mail to $email :: SUCCESS ::\n";  
}else {
        print LOG "[",`date`,"] Sending mail to $email :: FAILED ::\n";
}

close LOG;
```

Comment: It would help if you included the error an some details of the environment this code is supposed to run in.

Comment: What's the error message, etc? Stackoverflow hasn't implemented the Psychic feature yet. :)

Comment: What does C++ have to do with anything in this problem?

Answer (score 1):

See my [Troubleshooting Perl CGI scripts](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=380424). If that doesn't solve your problem, it will at least help you develop your question so you can get more help.

You might also like [brian's Guide to Solving Any Perl Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=376075).

Answer (score 0):

What error do you see?

In particular, what is in `$!` ?

It could be that the CGI process cannot execute Mutt - how about logging the script's userid and current path:

```
print LOG getpwuid($<) . "\n";
print LOG $ENV{PATH} . "\n";
```

Is the location of Mutt's executable in the path, and does that user (probably 'apache') have permission to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at using the Net::SMTP module, which will communicate directly with the mail server instead of depending on system tools.  This is a more portable solution, and avoids the whole permissions issue.